# Umbraco 6.0.3 missing content and media nodes

Tags: umbraco

I have just put up an Umbraco 6.0.3 site on eHosting and set all the directory permissions iaw our.umbraco.org/.../permissions. And this(http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/files-and-folders/permissions/perform-permissions-check) reports the permissions as "perfect". .NET framework set to 4.0 and App pool has been set and recycled.  Site shows up but no macros load and in the Umbraco UI there is only a Content node and a Media node, both the Content and Media trees are empty.

I can't think of anything else it can be.  This is the first V6 site I've put live.

Is there anything else I can check?

Cheers

Comment: Check the console for any errors. Specifically look for HTTP errors as these will give a clue as to why the web service that pulls the nodes down is erroring out.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your user login has permissions to view those nodes. The fact that you are not seeing any other sections (Settings, Developer, etc) suggests this.

Also - are you using any hostnames in Umbraco for the site (where you right click and click manage hostnames on the content node)? If so then check that the root node has a wildcard hostname added.

This is a case of retracing your steps over what you've done. If the other options don't work then you can do a database refresh too (copy the dev database to live). The fact you can login to the admin UI, says that you have the database working. However, is it possible that you've tweaked anything manually in the database?

Are you using MVC or ASP.NET rendering engine?

Check your log files and paste them here if all else fails and we'll try and help you out as best we can. You'll find them in App_Data/Logs/UmbracoLogs.txt

Answer (score 0):

When the content and media nodes failed to load for us in Umbraco 6.0.3 it was due to a bug in Courier which causes the back-office to malfunction if you are connected to a MySQL database (throws an exception complaining "Keyword not supported: 'charset'").

Courier interferes with many back office functions and in this case it is incorrectly assuming that you must be connecting to an MSSQL server.

The only solution was to uninstall Courier (which was OK for us because we'd already determined that there are too many show-stopping bugs for it to function as advertised).